# Broken Ubuntu Installation Intended to Replace Windows

Tags: grub2, system-installation, windows-7, usb-installation

I tried to install Ubuntu in an Encrypted Windows Desktop.

I downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop and checked the MD5 and the SHA256 SUM checks, and the iso image appeared non-corrupted.

Then I created a bootable flash USB with a program called Rufus. It took many hours for the flash drive to be ready to use.

Then I followed the prompts to install Ubuntu, but I got the error "Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda' failed. This is a fatal error."

I followed the process "Fixing a Broken System" via "via the LiveCD Terminal" as per this page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing , and now I have a terminal-like screen with the following message:

```
GNU GRUB Version 2.02~ beta 2-9

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB
lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible
device or file completions.

grub>_
```

WHAT SHOULD I DO TO GET UBUNTU FULLY INSTALLED?

I don't want any type of double loading, I just want plain ubuntu in this machine.

I am willing to go through the whole installation process again.

I am able to boot into Ubuntu USB and click the Try Ubuntu to access a terminal

Thank you

Comment: are you installing in EFI mode?

Comment: @ravery I'm sorry, I don't know; I'm a novice

Comment: @ravery How can I figure if I am in EFI mode?

Comment: is there a partition flagged as ESP that contains a folder named EFI?